# How to test AuthZ in Asp.NET core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been trying to find examples of how to test ASP.NET Core Web API without disabling Authorization.

The Authorization samples I have seen so far does not include unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Microsoft security example Weather Forecast and added unit test.

[Here AAD - single tenant](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki) is the Microsoft example that I modified.

The basic idea is to add a Test Scheme Identity provider in the unit test so we can do something like

```
// Arrange
var client = _factory
    .WithTestClaim(new List<Claim>() {
            new Claim("scp", "foobar")
     })
    .CreateClient();
```

The sample code is posted at.
https://github.com/xavierjohn/WeatherForcastWithAuth